# Ctrl alt shortcut key leads Ctrl alt del on my Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

Since few days ago I'm encountering a weird bug.. or new feature? When I press Ctrl-Alt key the shortcut key leads Ctrl-Alt-Del combo keys. So when I press Ctrl-Alt the screen turned to the blue screen. 
I've been working on Windows 10 for longs years. This is first time I got this bug. 
I searched Twitter and google but it seemed anyone had not this bug. 
I also checked some software installed, working on background. but I didn't install any suspicious software recently and the background items also seemed ok. I turned some items off and checked whether the problem solved or not. The autohotkey scripts were most suspicious ones but even after turned off the ones the problem still went on.

Is this bug not new feature, right? If this is bug, what can I do to try to fix this problem? thanks.

Comment: Ctrl-Alt-Del goes to Blue Lock the computer and has done for a very long time (prior to Windows 10).  Ctrl-Alt does nothing. Open an Admin Command Prompt, run dism.exe /online /clenaup-image /restorehealth  . Follow with SFC /SCANNOW , and restart when all is complete. Does this fix the issue?  Windows 10 Repair Install is the next step if not.

Comment: Thank you for your advice @John. I tried that today, the first one showed me that there's error in windows system, however second one solved nothing for me. You said I should do Rapair as the next step, but I don't want to if possible.. So I posted MS community here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/sfc-scannow-not-working-despite-theres-errorbugs/36b045a8-955e-44f7-bbd9-5c43af5d514c?tm=1582372539738
I hope there's possibility to solve the issue, anyway thank you.

Comment: The next step when DISM and SFC fail to correct is Windows 10 Repair Install. Normally (assuming this can correct the fault) it is an easy step to do (takes some time). Go to the Media Creation Link, take the second option, run in place and when the option presents itself, select Keep Everything. 

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10